# How to create auto updatable slideshow without any third-party scripts?

Tags: sharepoint-online

What i've already done:

1. Add 'Photos App'
2. Add 'Photos App' Web Part on my page
3. Change view to 'Slides'

After that i've started changing AJAX Options of my Web Part to

1. 'Enable Asynchronous Update' to true
2. 'Enable Asynchronous Automatic Refresh' to true
3. 'Automatic Refreshing Interval (seconds)' to 15

After these actions my wep part is still not work as i think it should.

Comment: and what are you expecting it to do and what results are you getting?

Comment: @EricAlexander, for example, http://codepen.io/cliffpyles/pen/tuwHG (it is updating without clicking on button)